# Why is my browser showing me the wrong site when I put in a certain IP - but just over wifi?

Tags: routing, vpn, nat, wireguard

ADDITIONAL Information: My ISP wifi router is a second `DHCP` server (since I can not disable it). The problem just comes up when I am connected via wifi. If I am connected via ethernet it works well so that I can connect to the other LANs router page. I wonder two things, first why the wifi connection will not route to the wireguard client, although the client hands out proper routes I can see on the machines that are connected over wifi:

```
default via 192.168.222.1
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0
192.168.111.0/24 via 192.168.222.22
192.168.222.0/24 via 192.168.222.1
```

Secondly, how can it be a wholly different site is displayed in the Firefox private browser tab?

---

I have two LANs connected over the internet with `wireguard`. `LAN1` has the wireguard server and `LAN2` has the client.

The client is acting as `DHCP` server so that it can send routes to all connected machines.

The routes say that if a machine in the `LAN2` wants to connect somewhere in `LAN1` it has to use the `wireguard client`. I can pinpoint this with

```
Mac-mini:~ mini$ traceroute 192.168.111.1
traceroute to 192.168.111.1 (192.168.111.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.222.22 (192.168.222.22)  6.580 ms  2.352 ms  1.972 ms
 2  * * *
 3  192.168.111.1 (192.168.111.1)  37.464 ms  26.298 ms  18.751 ms
```

So, the packages travels from `LAN2` client `192.168.222.223` to the wireguard client `.22` and then through the tunnel (which is ommitted, strangely) to `LAN1`.

In both networks, `.1` is the router's webpage.

Now, since today, when I open up `192.168.111.1` from `.222.0/24` it will not display the router page in the other lan, but the page in the same `LAN2`.

**It will show `192.168.222.1` when I asked for `192.168.111.1`**

I wonder how that is possible. I used a Firefox private site to do it and also Safari. In Firefox standard (not private) the site will bring up a site-not-found error (I tried to find the actual error message in network tools, but had no luck so far.).

On the wireguard client in `LAN2` I have two settings for `MASQUERADE` active since this was the only way I could setup a proper routing between both LANs. However, now I wonder if this might be wrong:

```
pi@pi:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 59 packets, 6406 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 38 packets, 4846 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 79 packets, 5310 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 28 packets, 2014 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   13  1066 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    forwarderPIL  anywhere             anywhere            
   47  3056 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere
```

The server has (I am unsure why it got the entry twice):

```
pi@RPi64:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 104K packets, 15M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 16092 packets, 2178K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11928 packets, 1202K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 18 packets, 1904 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    10.122.242.0/24      anywhere             /* wireguard-nat-rule */
  651 39632 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    10.122.242.0/24      anywhere             /* wireguard-nat-rule */
```

I have `ufw` running on the server, but even when disabled nothing changes. On the client `ufw` is disabled, although I managed to run things well in the past when having it set up with the right things.

Comment: What's 10.122.242.0/24?

Comment: That's the wireguard tunnel network. The client has `.3` and the server `.1`.

Comment: I have to add information: When I connect the machine that prints the wrong page via ethernet - instead of wifi - it works. It will show the LAN1 router web page in a private firefox tab. The wifi is done by my ISP router which hands out some fixed addresses as DHCP, too. I am not able to disable it, I can only chose to make it non-authorative (I think). Anyway, I really wonder why the wrong page will be shown over wifi, instead of just nothing.